# JFace resizing only the last group in a TitleAreaDialog

Tags: java, resize, swt, jface, titleareadialog

the program attached below creates a TitleAreaDialog with four groups in them. Each of the groups contain controls and the last one is "dynamic", i.e. when selecting an entry in the combo box, a certain number of controls is generated.

Now, fortunately, the dialog re-sizes automatically -- but I'd like to have more control over the resize. As it is right now, the dialog size is "distributed" evenly between the groups. What I would like to accomplish is to *only* enlarge (or shrink) the last group, even if the user resizes the dialog with the mouse. The size (height) of the three static groups should remain fixed.

Is there a way to achieve this?
TIA!

```
public class DialogExample extends ApplicationWindow {
    class MyDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {
        MyDialog(Shell shell) {
            super(shell);
            setShellStyle(getShellStyle() | SWT.MAX | SWT.RESIZE);
        }

        private Composite createComposite(Composite parent) {
            Composite c = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
            GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
            layout.horizontalSpacing = 10;
            c.setLayout(layout);
            c.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
            return c;
        }

        private Group createGroup(Composite parent, String title) {
            Group newGroup = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);
            newGroup.setText(title);
            newGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
            GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
            newGroup.setLayout(layout);          
            return newGroup;
        }

        private Group createGroup(Composite parent, int controlCount) {
            Group newGroup = createGroup(parent, "Group " + controlCount);
            for (int i = 0; i < controlCount; i++) {
                Label l = new Label(newGroup, SWT.NONE);
                l.setText("Label " + (i + 1));
            }          
            return newGroup;
        }

        private Group createControlGroup(final Composite parent) {          
            final Group newGroup = createGroup(parent, "Control Group");
            final Combo combo = new Combo(newGroup, SWT.READ_ONLY);
            combo.add("1");
            combo.add("2");
            combo.add("3");
            combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                      for (Control c: newGroup.getChildren()) {
                           if (c != combo) {
                                c.dispose();
                           }
                      }
                      for (int i = 0; i <combo.getSelectionIndex() + 1; i++) {
                          Label l = new Label(newGroup, SWT.None);
                          l.setText("Dynamic Label " + (i + 1));
                      }
                      parent.getShell().pack();
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                  }
            });
        return newGroup;
     }

     public void create() {
        super.create();
        setTitle("Title");
        setMessage("Message");
     }

     protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
        Composite main = createComposite(parent);
        createGroup(main, 1);
        createGroup(main, 2);
        createGroup(main, 3);     
        createControlGroup(main);
        return main;
      }
    }

    public DialogExample() 
    {
      super(null);
    }

    public void run() {
      setBlockOnOpen(true);
      open();
      Display.getCurrent().dispose();
    }

    protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
      Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.CENTER);
      label.setText("Dialog example");
      TitleAreaDialog dialog = new MyDialog(parent.getShell());

      dialog.open();
      return label;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
      new DialogExample().run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is that you use the following:

```
newGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

which means that each group should stretch across the parent and occupy as much space as possible.

You can fix that by using:

```
newGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false));
```

for the components that should not stretch vertically and:

```
newGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
```

for those that should.

---

If you haven't read "Understanding Layouts in SWT" yet, please do so [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html).